# Google Fusion tables add a heat/polygon map and remove markers

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am using `Fusion tables` to create visualizations of my data. More specifically, we are trying to create a US map by zip codes and color them based on some weightage (defined by business logic).

I downloaded Google Fusion Table details from here : https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1Lae-86jeUDLmA6-8APDDqazlTOy1GsTXh28DAkw#rows:id=1 
And create a zip code to weightage mapping. Finally merged these two tables together so that the final table has :

```
zipcode, geometry , weightage
```

However, Google only shows the map with markers. I tried `change feature styles` etc but couldn't get it work. Documentation isn't too clear on this topic either. Please let me know what's the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. Related to the markers: assuming you use the correct  column for the geometry: depending on the zoom and amount of features the layer will show dots instead of the shapes(polygons), you'll need to set  a zoom(minZoom) for the map where the polygons will be shown
2. Related to the polygon-color: go to **change feature styles>Fill color>buckets**

   Select the desired amount of buckets and the column(weightage), click on the link "use this range". Now select different colors for the buckets(when you want to) and  click "Save" to apply the settings.

Possible result(using 8 buckets for column SUMBLKPOP  for the polygon-color)

```js
function initialize() {
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.8781136, -87.6297981),
      zoom: 8,
      minZoom:5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    
  layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      heatmap: { enabled: false },
      query: {
        select: "col11",
        from: "1Lae-86jeUDLmA6-8APDDqazlTOy1GsTXh28DAkw",
        where: ""
      },
      options: {
        styleId: 590,
        templateId: 585
      }
    });


  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
body,html{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
#googft-mapCanvas{height:100%;width:100%;}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>

<div id="googft-mapCanvas"></div>
```